# Fieldset like div container with headers/subheader

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a fieldset in React which would allow me to add any element within the outside border (e.g. a button etc.).
I'm looking for a way to make the make the element within the border transparent (where it says "For visiting us"), so the true background of the page is nicely visible.

With an implementation like the below, the background is set to black explicitly. I'd like to avoid it, and have no background. But then, the border line is shown.

Is there a clever way around this?

Thanks!

```js
function ThankYou(){
  return(
    <div className="thankYouParent">
      <div className="thankYouBox">
        <label className="borderText"> For visiting us </label>
        <label className="thankYouText">Thank You</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThankYou />,
  root
)
```

```css
.thankYouParent {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: center;
}

.thankYouBox {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 75vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

.thankYouText {
  font-family: interstateBold;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
}

.borderText {
  font-family: interstateRegular;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
  bottom: -1.5vh;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```